# Error in APEXBox: Error CS1501: No overload for method 'Connect' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

When I am try to code my Discord bot, this error comes up:

> Error: "/Users/jadenlee/Projects/APEXBot/APEXBot/MyBot.cs(19,19): Error CS1501: No overload for method 'Connect' takes 1 arguments (CS1501) (APEXBot)"

This is my current code right now.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;

namespace APEXBot
{
    class MyBot
    {
        DiscordClient discord;

        public MyBot()
        {
            discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
            {
                x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
                x.LogHandler = Log;
            });

            discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
            {
                //    Error here
                await discord.Connect("MzAzMzQyMzAyNjUzMzE3MTIx.C9X34w.loaFfJMxb1N2o7Aoqf0H4xVMnGo");
            });
        }

        private void Log(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. First, the error message is completely descriptive: there is not method on `DiscordClient ` that takes one `String` argument. Youe needs to check what methods are supported by the API. Second, please read carefully [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) on using words like ASAP in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use method with two parameters

```
await discord.Connect("MzAzMzQyMzAyNjUzMzE3MTIx.C9X34w.loaFfJMxb1N2o7Aoqf0H4xVMnGo",TokenType.Bot);
```

Comment: This worked, but now it says
`System.Exception has been thrown
You must send data by web socket after web socket is opened!`

Comment: It also says `Record Overflow` next to it